# public data on vehicle speed/acceleration for a route, for multiple trips

Tags: data-request, transportation, traffic

Is there a public database containing vehicle speed or vehicle acceleration with location info like GPS, in a particular route, (for one trip or multiple trips)?

1. latitude-x, longitude-x, speed1 or acceleration1
2. latitude-y, longitude-y, speed2 or acceleration2 etc...

I tried to find data uploaded from some "trip recorder" device or car dash-camera recorded data, but I don't find any such data.

Answer (score 1):

You can derive speed and acceleration from timestamp and latitude/longitude with .gpx files ([GPS Exchange Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_Exchange_Format)), although you'll have to use GPS traces that are dense.

One source of public .gpx files is [OpenStreetMap Traces](http://www.openstreetmap.org/traces).

One method to compute velocity (and elevation profile) from a .gpx file is [gpxplot](https://github.com/astanin/gpxplot). If you do the calculations yourself, make sure to use the [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to calculate distances from lat/long.

---

([my source](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/5904))

Answer (score 1):

Many years later... (to anyone of interest), found this by chance, gyro, accelerometer vs long, lat for a study to predcit is the former one are more accuracte by using RNNs https://databank.illinois.edu/datasets/IDB-5975383